# Every Borel measure can be written as a Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I was thinking about this and I could not get to an answer. To illustrate my point, assume I have a random variable $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and a measure $\mu$ and I want to compute its expectation:

$$EX=\int X d\mu$$

Can I, WITHOUT loss of generality, assume that I can represent this integral as a Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral?

Comment: I don't understand your question. This is by definition a Lebesgue (and thus also Lebesgue-Stieltjes) integral.

Comment: Lebesgue-Stieltjes integrals only make sense when the underlying space $\Omega$ is $\mathbb{R}$ (or an appropriate subset).

Comment: It is true. Assume $\Omega=\mathbb{R}$. I did not say that the measure of an interval $\mu$ can be written as $\mu((a,b])=\mu(b)-\mu(a)$. I want to know if I can write $\mu((a,b])=G(b)-G(a)$, for some distribution function $G$. I was not clear I think.

Answer (score 4):

Provided that $\Omega = \mathbb{R}$ and  $\mu$ assigns finite measure to bounded sets, the answer is yes.  Set $$G(x) = \begin{cases} \mu([0,x]), & x \ge 0 \\ -\mu((x,0)), & x < 0. \end{cases}$$
Then you can check that $G$ is nondecreasing and right continuous (use countable additivity), and for each bounded interval $(a,b]$  we have $\mu((a,b]) = G(b) - G(a)$.  You can also verify that $\int X\,d\mu = \int X\,dG$.